# Nested column-flowed flexbox width shrinked

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm struggling with a popover design with nested colmun-flowed flexbox. My problem is that when the "2nd level" flexbox wraps, it keeps its initial width for some reason, so it overflows.

The way I see it, as the problem is on the "perpendicular" axis, the only property that could have an effect on this is the "align-items". But I tried every possible combination, without success.
Setting a fixed width for the wrapper works, but then it's not responsive anymore. Small caveat: the number of inputs is dynamic and unknown in advance.

Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to make :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button[type=submit] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: end;
}

.popover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.popover-content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 0;
}
  
.wrapper {
  min-height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="popover">
  <div class="popover-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <form class="form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT : Bonus question : can someone explain why it does this ?
My guess would be that the width of the form is computed before rendering the wrapping, so then the size of the wrapper is constrained by the computed size of the form which happens to be the size of the first column.

Comment: Do you need `.popover-content`width do adopt to the multi-column representation of labels avoiding overflow issue?

Comment: @OlegBrynzovskii Exactly

Answer (score 0):

I edited a bit your source code. Please, take a look. There are unneeded `flex` definitions that I removed.

```css
label {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button[type=submit] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: end;
}

.popover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popover-content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
  
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="popover">
  <div class="popover-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <form class="form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the display that you want?
Remove **wrap** property inside element: **.wrapper**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button[type=submit] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: end;
}

.popover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.popover-content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 0;
}
  
.wrapper {
  min-height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="popover">
  <div class="popover-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <form class="form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid the scrollbar and have several columns instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code 
In .wrapper class change  flex-flow: column wrap to  flex-flow: wrap

```css
   

 * {
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button[type=submit] {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: end;
}

.popover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.popover-content {
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 90vw;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  min-height: 0;
}
  
.wrapper {
  min-height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

```html
    <div class="popover">
  <div class="popover-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <form class="form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>sample value</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that I can no longer have a single column if it fits in the screen. But it might do the trick is I don't find anything else

Comment: Another issue I just noticed is that it really looks like crap when the labels are not all the same length (which is the case)

Comment: Yes, you right then apply label width to avoid alignment issues.